# Designing bots using Node.JS, that run with random timeouts and a common routine

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing

I'd like to use Node.JS to design some bots. Here are the requirements of these bots:

- There are upto 10 'bots'. Im not sure how to do this in NodeJS,
  considering its single threaded, Im assuming if there are 10 worker
  items that are asynchronous, that will be representative of 10
  'bots'?
- Bots perform a basic REST task, like a POST to a remote server. Assume every POST is a success (or assume we dont care if there is a failure). While the remote server is the same and the function is the same (POST), there may be variants in arguments, and each bot will supply the variable arguments, like payload to POST
- Bots should somewhat model human behavior by randomly sleeping for some k seconds before firing off a task. Then it  queues itself for another random k seconds before performing another task. This adds a level of complexity that Im unable to wrap my head around - if I use a sleep/timeout function like setTimeout or setInterval will 10 of such workers sleep in parallel or sleep serially. If they sleep serially then I dont have 10 bots, instead I have 10 serial workers queued in order of sleep!

What I have tried so far:
Since Im new to NodeJS, i havent been able to accurately find the right way to deal with this.

- I looked into [beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd) which is a workqueue, but it appears serial that the consumer service will order items serially
- Im currently evaluating [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async) but it appears that the parallelism is a 'barrier' where all parallel jobs will proceed to the next iteration only after all parallel jobs have finished the function to be executed in parallel, but in my case I'd like, for example, bot 3 to be requeued and sleeping on its 2nd iteration even though bot 7 is on a long sleep in its first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple framework:

```
var bot = {
    act: function() {
        //make post request here
        var delay = Math.random() * 500; /*set random delay to mimic human */
        setTimeout(this.act.bind(this), delay);
    }
}

var bots = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bots.push(Object.create(bot));
}

bots.forEach(function(bot) {
    bot.act();
});
```

We have a master bot template, the `bot` variable. `bot.act` is a function that will send the POST request, then set a timeout on itself after a delay. The rest is just boilerplate, adding 10 bots to a list, and starting each bot. It's really that simple... no work queues, no async parallel...

Comment: I believe inside the setTimeout, the call to act should be instead this.act ? without that, I get a "ReferenceError: act is not defined". And when I replace it with this.act, I find that act doesn't run in a loop! it runs only twice - once from bot.act and then the first iteration of act. Any ideas?

Comment: @nthacker sorry about that, I've updated my answer. We just have to bind the timeout to the current bot context.

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

Answer (score 2):

The asynchronous nature of javascript means that when each 'bot' is sleeping it doesn't block and cause the other bots to sleep. For example, in this code:

```
'use strict';

var start = Date.now();

var printTime = function() {
    console.log(Date.now() - start + 'ms');
};

setTimeout(function() {
    printTime();
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
    printTime();
}, 1000);
```

Should print (approximately):

```
500ms
1000ms
```

Rather than:

```
500ms
1500ms
```

Something like this should work just fine:

```
'use strict';

var fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Each bot waits between 5 and 30 seconds
var minDelay = 5000;
var maxDelay = 30000;

var numBots = 10;

var botTask = function() {
    fetch('http://somewhere.com/foo', { method: 'POST', body: 'a=1' });
};

var getDelay = function() {
    return minDelay + Math.random() * (maxDelay - minDelay);
};

var runBot = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        botTask();
        runBot();
    }, getDelay());
};

for (var i = 0; i !== numBots; i++) {
    runBot();
}
```